# Document Collaboration database schema

Tags: database, format, collaboration

I‘m currently developing an app where multiple users can edit a rich text document. The sentences a user has changed or added should be marked like in the image below of Google Docs.

[image: Google Docs shared editing]

The ID of the user/author must therefore be stored in the document itself (metadata) or related to the document and added/changed sentence in a database.

What would you recommend?

How would you design the data format or database schema?

Cheers!

Comment: I'm not sure about this will help or not. This article describes way to implement real-time collaborative text editor using CRDTs.
https://hackernoon.com/building-conclave-a-decentralized-real-time-collaborative-text-editor-a6ab438fe79f

Comment: There are two ways to implement a collaborative text editor like Google Doc.
One using Operation Transformation and second using CRDTs. The above article describes second approach. So the database schema you are looking for is either one of them.